# Conditionally mount components based on their return value

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to check if a component renders null ?

```
const ComponentA = ({ shouldRender }) => {
  if(!shouldRender){
     return null;
  }

  return <div>Foo</div>
}


const ComponentB = () => <div>Bar</div>

// I want this component to render ComponentA
const ComponentC = () => {
  return <ComponentA shouldRender /> || <ComponentB />;
}

// I want this component to render ComponentB, as ComponentA returns null
const ComponentD = () => {
  return <ComponentA shouldRender={false} /> || <ComponentB />;
}
```

Renders `<div>Foo</div>`, as expected

```
<ComponentC />
```

I want this to render `<div>Bar</div>`, but ComponentA is mounted and renders `null`

```
<ComponentD />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible. You will have to either render conditionally on the outer component:

```js
const ComponentD = () => {
  return shouldRender ? <ComponentA shouldRender={true} /> : <ComponentB />;
}
```

or render both component, but giving them the `shouldRender` property, as a component rendering null is actually not displayed:

```js
const ComponentD = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ComponentA shouldRender={shouldRender} />
      <ComponentB shouldRender={!shouldRender} />
    </>
  );
}
```

EDIT: If the condition for rendering or not `ComponentA` is inside the component, and complex enough for you don't want to duplicate it, you should probably externalize it in a hook, used by both components A and B.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I maybe did not write a good example. The condition to render the component is performed inside the component itself:

`const ComponentA = () => shouldRender ? <div>Foo</div> : null`

Using a shared hook was what I thought initially, but wasn't sure if there was a "simpler" solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
const ComponentC = () => {
    return shouldRender ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />;
}
```